# How to properly assign property to function scope?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-decorator

I've been experimenting Typescript Decorators recently to try solving a "problem" I have within my application. I'm using a JS bridge to feed TS code to both Android and iOS, and at the moment we declare functions like this:

index.js

```js
import foo from './bar'

global.App = function() {
  this.foo = foo;
};
```

The above will make the `foo` function to be available on the native side of the bridge

I wanted to write a decorator to apply on that `foo` method which would "register" itself on the `global.App` but I've failed in that task.

Here's the decorator that works:

```js
export const Task = (target, propertyKey, descriptor) => {
    let originalMethod = descriptor.value;
    descriptor.value = (...args) => originalMethod.apply(target, args);

    if (!global.App) {
        global.App = function () { 
            this.foo = descriptor.value;
        };
    }
    
    return descriptor;
}
```

How could I add another method to that `global.App` function?

Comment: Your code sets `global.App` to a `function` but then you just try to set its value as a simple value. It's not clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Whenever we set a property to that `global.App` function, that property is then accessible on the native side via the bridge and thus we can call the method we set to that property

Comment: There is probably a custom behaviour in your bridge that _calls_ `global.App`. As pointed out by Pointy's comment, in one case you set it as a function, in the other as an already existing object. Also note that you _may_ be misled by `this`.

Comment: In that context, this refers to the inner function I'm assigning to `global.App` right? How could I add another property to `global.App`?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the `foo` method is only added once because the first time the decorator is called `global.App` is defined and the branch that adds `foo` to `global.App` is never re-entered.

Secondly, `global.App` and `foo` would be overwritten each time and not maintained through repeated calls to the decorator.

Adding another branch that handles adding the method after the first call and dynamically assigns the name of the method, which I believe is given to the decorator in `propertyKey`, would permit multiple methods to be added.

```
export const Task = (target, propertyKey, descriptor) => {
    let originalMethod = descriptor.value;
    descriptor.value = (...args) => originalMethod.apply(target, args);

    if (!global.App) {
        global.App = function () { 
            this[propertyKey] = descriptor.value;
        };
    } else {
        global.App[propertyKey] = descriptor.value;
    }
    
    return descriptor;
}
```

Something like this might work.

Comment: Didn't work, the global.App is undefined after each step.. Still trying to figure out why.. basically I've put a console.log after each assign and it yields undefined

Comment: Ok, perhaps separate out the assignment section to be sure its defined.

Answer (score 1):

After wandering around SO for some time I've found a workaround for this... perhaps I lack the knowledge of TS/JS to know exactly what I wanted to do here, but anyways, my solution was to register every task decorated and then on the `index.js` I get those tasks and register them on the `global.App` function.

Something like this

task.ts

```
export const TaskRegistry = {};

 export const Task = (target, propertyKey, descriptor) => {
   const originalMethod = descriptor.value;
   descriptor.value = (...args) => originalMethod.apply(target, args);

   TaskRegistry[propertyKey] = descriptor.value;

   return descriptor;
 };
```

index.js

```js
// eslint-disable-next-line func-names
global.App = function () {
   // eslint-disable-next-line consistent-this
   const self = this;

   Object.keys(TaskRegistry).forEach((key) => {
     self[key] = TaskRegistry[key];
   });
}
```